# WFFM Custom Save Action :- pass response data to thankyou page

Tags: sitecore, web-forms-for-marketers

I am using WFFM Custom Save action methods. Here I am executing some service and getting response , I have to display response  in next page.I used below code but its not working.

```cs
internal class WffmCustomSaveAction : WffmSaveAction
{
    public override void Execute(ID formId, AdaptedResultList adaptedFields, ActionCallContext actionCallContext, params object[] data)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("<html>");
        sb.AppendFormat(@"<body onload='document.forms[""form""].submit()'>");
        sb.AppendFormat("<form name='form' action='{0}' method='post'>", "http://local.website/thankyoupage");
        sb.AppendFormat("<input type='hidden' name='id' value='{0}'>", "id123");
        // Other params go here
        sb.Append("</form>");
        sb.Append("</body>");
        sb.Append("</html>");

        HttpContext.Current.Server.Transfer(sb.ToString());
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use a SaveAction to do the redirect to your thankyou page. You can use the Sitecore pipelines to change the redirect url. A working example can be found [here](http://ggullentops.blogspot.be/2016/07/sitecore-wffm-act-on-success.html) for MVC forms (Webforms pipelines are mentioned as well, but without code example).

> All comes down to finding the correct pipelines in
>   Sitecore. In this case you need a pipeline in case of success. But be aware:  there is a big difference between the webforms and mvc solution.
>
> **Webforms**: The pipeline in case of webforms are: `<successAction>`
>    This can be found in `Sitecore.Forms.config`.
>
> **Mvc**: The pipeline in case of mvc are: `<wffm.success>`
>   This can be found in `Sitecore.MvcForms.config`.